# Add eventListener to buttons to change class onmouseup/down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, addeventlistener

I have several red and black buttons and I want to add 'onmousedown' and 'onmouseup' events to the set of red buttons that share the same class ("button red").

onmousedown I want to change add the class "opaque" and onmouseup remove it again.

So onmousedown the red button which has been "selected" goes slightly transparent and onmouseup goes back to normal (red). The other buttons remain unaffected.

**css**

```
.button {
   background-color: black;
   color: white;
   height: 30px;
   width: 150px; 
   text-align: center;
}

.button.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.button.red.opaque { 
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

**javascript (so far)**

```
var classname = this.document.getElementsByClassName("button red");

for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) { 
   classname[i].addEventListener('onmousedown', classList.add("opaque"), false);
   classname[i].addEventListener('onmouseup', classList.remove("opaque"), false);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, your question should contain [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). FWIW you can do this with CSS. Is there a reason you're doing it with JS?

Comment: Can you add your HTML

Comment: Your selectors are wrong. `.button red opaque` looks for `<opaque>` elements (not classes) that are descendants of `<red>` elements (not classes) that are descendants of elements that use the `button` class. It should be `.button.red.opaque`. Same with your `.button red` selector.

Comment: `"button red"` is not a valid name for a class. `getElementsByClassName` doesn't support selecting by multiple classNames at once, use `querySelectorAll()` for that with a proper CSS selector. And `.button red opaque` means an `<opaque>` node inside a `<red>` node inside some node with the class `button`. You probably mean `.button.red.opaque`

Comment: and use semicolons at the end of property definitions in CSS, not commas

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` does support multiple classNames: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with CSS only.

```css
button {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

button:active {
  background-color: salmon;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<button>Click Me!</button>
```

To address this in JS like you're doing you will need to fix a couple of things.

As mentioned in the comments, there was a type for `getElementsByClassName()`. I would use `querySelectorAll()` instead of `getElementsByClassName()` because it is more flexible in how you can select elements.

`classList` is a property of a DOM element and cannot be used on its own. Do this `element.classList.add( 'class' )`, not this `classList.add( 'class' )`.

Your CSS selectors were incorrect, i.e. `.button red opaque` will try to select an element with the class `.button` that contains an element of `<red>` that has an element of `<opaque>`.

There might be something wrong with your markup and selectors but I don't have your HTML to verify. I assumed your markup for my example.

```js
var $btns = [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '.button.red' ) );

$btns.map( function ( btn ) {

  btn.addEventListener( 'mousedown', function ( e ) {
    btn.classList.add( 'opaque' );
  } );

  btn.addEventListener( 'mouseup', function ( e ) {
    btn.classList.remove( 'opaque' );
  } );
  
} );
```

```css
.button {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.button.red {
  background-color: indianred;
}

.button.opaque {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<button class="button red">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: It's a good solution, but doesn't answer the OP's question about his code.

Comment: Great, but does not answer the actual question.

Comment: True, I'll add the JS solution after.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do with css, but here is a solution to add jquery listener on mouse up and mouse down.

```js
$('.button' + '.red').each(function() {
  $(this).mousedown(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('opaque');
  });
  $(this).mouseup(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('opaque');
  });
});
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}

.opaque {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button red">Button</button>
<button class="button black">Button</button>
```

Comment: You can do `.button.red` instead of `'.button' + '.red'` and cache `$( this )` instead of repeatedly calling it.

Answer (score 2):

- No iteration (loops) needed
- Wrapped buttons in a `<form>` tag
- Using **[HTMLFormControlsCollection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection)** to access buttons
- Used **only 2 eventListeners** for **20 red buttons** mixed with **20 black buttons** by using [**Event Delegation**](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm)
- CSS animation via **[`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-property)** property

### Demo

```js
var form = document.forms.main;

form.addEventListener('mousedown', fade, false);
form.addEventListener('mouseup', fade, false);

function fade(e) {

  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {

      e.target.classList.toggle('opq');
  }
}
```

```css
.btn {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  transition: all .5s ease
}

.btn.red.opq {
  opacity: 0.7;
  transition: all .5s ease
}
```

```html
<form id='main'>

  <button class='red btn' type='button'>RED</button>
  <button class='red btn' type='button'>RED</button>
  <button class='btn' type='button'>BLK</button>
  <button class='red btn' type='button'>RED</button>
  <button class='btn' type='button'>BLK</button>
  <button class='red btn' type='button'>RED</button>
  <button class='btn' type='button'>BLK</button>
  <button class='red btn' type='button'>RED</button>
  <button class='btn' type='button'>BLK</button>
  <button class='red btn' type='button'>RED</button>
  <button class='btn' type='button'>BLK</button>
  <button class='btn' type='button'>BLK</button>
  <button class='red btn' type='button'>RED</button>
  <button class='btn' type='button'>BLK</button>
  <button class='red btn' type='button'>RED</button>
  <button class='red btn' type='button'>RED</button>
  <button class='btn' type='button'>BLK</button>
  <button class='red btn' type='button'>RED</button>
  <button class='btn' type='button'>BLK</button>
  <button class='red btn' type='button'>RED</button>
  <button class='btn' type='button'>BLK</button>
  <button class='red btn' type='button'>RED</button>
  <button class='btn' type='button'>BLK</button>
  <button class='red btn' type='button'>RED</button>
  <button class='btn' type='button'>BLK</button>
  <button class='btn' type='button'>BLK</button>
  <button class='red btn' type='button'>RED</button>
  <button class='btn' type='button'>BLK</button>
  <button class='red btn' type='button'>RED</button>
  <button class='red btn' type='button'>RED</button>
  <button class='btn' type='button'>BLK</button>
  <button class='red btn' type='button'>RED</button>
  <button class='btn' type='button'>BLK</button>
  <button class='red btn' type='button'>RED</button>
  <button class='btn' type='button'>BLK</button>
  <button class='red btn' type='button'>RED</button>
  <button class='btn' type='button'>BLK</button>
  <button class='red btn' type='button'>RED</button>
  <button class='btn' type='button'>BLK</button>
  <button class='btn' type='button'>BLK</button>

</form>
```

Comment: It's not necessary to wrap buttons in a `<form>` tag.

Comment: It's necessary if you use HTMLFormControlsCollection which makes forms very easy to handle, when OP expands beyond buttons. Plus it's necessary to wrap buttons in a common ancestor in order to exploit bubbling (event delegation which makes it possible to use a single eventlistener for an event  covering an unlimited amount of event.targets.)

Comment: That may be true, but what if the buttons are spread all over the page? I also like the event delegation, but what if there are multiple `mouseup` and `mousedown` events from different elements in the ancestor? Use this `e.target.classList.toggle( 'opq', !e.target.classList.contains( 'opq' ) );` to get rid of an if statement.

Comment: You are correct, I'm used to writing for more than one state I entirely forgot about `.toggle()`, updated thanks.

Comment: `e.stopPropagation()` for mixed events and a custom `eventTrigger()` if it's  really cluttered (which means I probably inherited  someone's mess).

Answer (score 1):

```
var classname = this.document.getElementsByClassName("button red");

for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) { 
  classname[i].addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
    this.classList.add("opaque")
  }, false);
  classname[i].addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
    this.classList.remove("opaque")
  }, false);
}
```

CSS:

```
.button {
   background-color: black;
   color: white;
   height: 30px;
   width: 150px;
   text-align: center;
}

.button.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.button.red.opaque { 
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

1. `getElementByClassName` should be `getElementsByClassName`
2. You need to pass a function as the second argument of your event listener
3. You need to give context to the `classList` property
4. The correct names for the events are `mousedown` and `mouseup`
5. CSS properties need to end in semicolons
6. CSS selectors are incorrect

Comment: And that is not going to work either. Going to get an error that can't read classList of undefined.

Comment: Correct, I just fixed it